# Creating TestBuild and Release Build in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I have created a click-once solution in visual studio. I want to have two separate builds for this solution. A test build and a release build. I need this because i need a specific amount of users to be able to test some functionality before releasing it to all other users. Is this possible with Visual Studio 2015 or do i need another software for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this using a .cmd file with MSBuild commands. 
I had a build for DEV and a Build for Prod. 
You can set the ProductName to product_DEV for your dev build.
The disadvantage is that, if it's on offline app then your users will have the DEV copy installed. So I used my app as a online app.

Here's a link to more info on MSBuild with clickonce:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx